# Add a new/custom property to workflow inbox in AEM 6.2

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I have a requirement to have a new priority property rendered in the classic UI inbox when a user set the priority property during the initiation of the workflow in [AEM 6.2](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/authoring/using/inbox.html).

I see this an OOTB functionality in [AEM 6.3](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/authoring/using/inbox.html)  but not in AEM 6.2 and the new [Workitem](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/workflow/exec/WorkItem.html) handles priority. I understand the possibility of customizing the inbox in AEM 6.3.

How can I leverage the inbox customization in AEM 6.2?

I'm currently following the approach mentioned in [Adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5026766).

[image]

Even after updating columns list, I don't see the new column in the inbox.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you followed would work for CQ5.
    For AEM 6.2 follow the steps :

```
Taking a example to show the name of the workflow initiator 

1) /libs/cq/workflow/content/notifications/workitemdetails/items/content/items/itemdetails/items/well/items
create a new node : nt:unstructured
(ex)
fieldLabel - String - Started By
name - String - startedBy
renderReadOnly - Boolean - true
showEmptyInReadOnly - Boolean - true
sling:resourceType - String - granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield

2) /libs/cq/workflow/components/inbox/list/json.jsp
add code :

WorkflowStatus wfStatus = res.adaptTo(WorkflowStatus.class);                
if (wfStatus != null) {
   List<Workflow> workflows = wfStatus.getWorkflows(true);
   if(workflows.size() > 0) {
     String initiator = workflows.get(0).getInitiator();
     writer.key("startedBy").value(initiator);
   }
}

Note :
key name (startedBy) should match the name defined in new node

3) /libs/cq/workflow/gui/components/inbox/clientlibs/inbox/js/model/InboxItemModel.js
toJSON: function() {
.
.
.
startedBy: Granite.I18n.getVar(this.get("startedBy")) || "",
}

Now you can see the custom node entry in /notifications.html]

screen shot :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpoY9.png
```